# PyQt/Pyside: storing individual value in QPushButtons(or QWidgets in general)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qpushbutton, slot

Suppose I have some `QPushButton`s displayed in a `QListWidget` or `QTableWidget`. The `QPushButtons` connect to the same slot function that carries out the same action for their relative list item or table row.

I am not sure if I am thinking in the right direction:

Suppose that the list items or table rows are created in a `for` loop, looping a list, for example. During the creation of the list item, or table row, along with the `QPushButton` in it, I am supposed to store some sort of data, or id, into the `QPushButton`, so that when the `QPushButton` is clicked, its connected slot will know which `QPushButton` is clicked and carry out some operation specifically to the `QPushButton`'s parent list item/table row. (assuming I am using the same one slot function for all the `QPushButton`s)

So my question is: Given that the list items or table rows are created in a `for` loop of a list, how do I store some sort of list-related value(s) into the `QPushButton` and how do I retrieve the value(s) inside the slot function?

I suppose my question isn't really bound to `QPushButton`s. The same question can go to `QCheckBox`es, `QLineEdit`s, or any `QWidget`s in general as long as they can send out signals.

Comment: Assuming that the list or table doesn't change its shape (row/column count, or item order), the simplest solution is to use lambdas: `button.clicked.connect(lambda _, row=row: self.myFunction(row))`. For any other situations, a better approach is to not use index widgets, but implement a proper custom item delegate that would return the widget as an *editor*, and then use `openPersistentEditor()` in the view for each item you need to show the widget.

Comment: A more general solution for cell-widgets is to use the [indexAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) method of the view to get a model-index from the current cell-widget coordinates. Within the slot, you can use `self.sender()` or `QApplication.focusWidget()` to get a reference to the cell-widget. So a simple one-liner would be: `index = self.tableWidget.indexAt( self.sender().pos())`. If you prefer to get an item instead, there's also an equivalent [itemAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemAt) method.

Comment: @ekhumoro It's worth noticing that delegates don't necessarily create editors with the given parent (for instance, when using a dialog), nor there's absolute guarantee about their final geometry: for instance, the default line edit editor extends its right edge beyond the right of the index, but a custom one might choose to do otherwise (possibly extending on the left), resulting in a wrong `indexAt()`. Unfortunately, `indexForEditor()` and `editorForIndex()` are private functions. When uncertain, I normally "link" the QPersistentModelIndex to the editor or its signals/slots.

Comment: @musicamante I am only suggesting using `indexAt` with *cell-widgets*. Delegates automatically get the relevant model-index within e.g. `createEditor`, so it usually isn't necessary to perform that extra step. This doesn't mean I'm recommending the use of cell-widgets over delegates. I never actually use cell-widgets myself, so the above solution is just something I suggest whenever the topic comes up on SO. Many people still seem to find them convenient, but if Qt wasn't so concerned about backwards compatibility, they probably would have removed the index-widget APIs long ago.